# Solution verification: Proving that the existance of step functions bounding a function $f$ implies $f$ is integrable.

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

Suppose that for all $\varepsilon > 0$ there are step functions $s_1 \le f$ and $s_2 \ge f$ such that $$\int_a^b s_2 - \int_a^b s_1 < \varepsilon.$$ Prove that $f$ is integrable.

---

Let $s_1,s_2$ be given. Let $\pi_1, \pi_2$ be partitions of $[a,b]$ such that, for all $\varepsilon > 0,$
\begin{align*}
U(s_1,\pi_1) - L(s_1,\pi_1) &< \varepsilon/2, \\
U(s_2,\pi_2) - L(s_2,\pi_2) &< \varepsilon/2,
\end{align*} and let $\pi$ be the partition of $[a,b]$ containing both $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$. Then we have that
\begin{align*}
U(s_1,\pi) - L(s_1,\pi) \le U(s_1,\pi_1) - L(s_1,\pi_1) &< \varepsilon/2, \\
U(s_2,\pi) - L(s_2,\pi) \le U(s_2,\pi_2) - L(s_2,\pi_2) &< \varepsilon/2.
\end{align*}

By definition, we have that $L(s_2,\pi) = \sum_{i=1}^n m_i(t_i - t_{i-1})$, where $m_i = \inf\{s_2(x) : t_{i-1}\le x \le t_i\}.$ Notice that $s_2$ is an upper bound of $f$, so $s_2 \ge \sup\{ f(x) : t_{i-1} \le x \le t_i \}$. Similarly, $\sup\{ f(x) : t_{i-1} \le t_i \}$ is a lower bound of $s_2$. However, it may not be the greatest lower bound, and so $\inf\{s_2(x) : t_{i-1}\le x \le t_i\} \ge \sup\{ f(x) : t_{i-1} \le x \le t_i \}$. Together, this implies that $U(s_2,\pi) \ge L(s_2,\pi) \ge U(f,\pi)$.

Then, $U(s_1,\pi) = \sum_{i=1}^b M_i(t_i - t_{i-1})$, where $M_i = \sup\{s_1(x) : t_{i-1} \le x \le t_i\}$. Since $s_1 \le f,$ $f$ is an upper bound of $s_1$ on any given interval, so $\sup\{s_1(x) : t_{i-1} \le x \le t_i\} \le f(x)$ for $t_{i-1} \le x \le t_i$. Similarly, $\sup\{s_1(x) : t_{i-1} \le x \le t_i\}$ is a lower bound of $f$ for any given interval, so $\sup\{s_1(x) : t_{i-1} \le x \le t_i\} \le \inf\{ f(x) : t_{i-1} \le x \le t_i \}$. Therefore, $L(s_1,\pi) \le U(s_1,\pi) \le L(f,\pi)$.

Now if we show that $U(f,\pi) - L(f,\pi) < \varepsilon,$ then we are done. So note that
\begin{align*}
\varepsilon &> U(s_1,\pi) + U(s_2,\pi) - (L(s_1,\pi) + L(s_2,\pi)) \\
&\ge U(f,\pi) + U(s_1,\pi) - (L(f,\pi) + L(s_2,\pi))
\end{align*}

We have that
\begin{align*}
\int_a^b s_i &= \inf \{U(s_i,\pi)\} \le U(s_i,\pi), \\
\int_a^b s_i &= \sup \{L(s_i,\pi)\} \ge L(s_i,\pi).
\end{align*}
Therefore,
\begin{align*}
\varepsilon &> U(s_1,\pi) + U(f,\pi) - L(f,\pi) - L(s_2,\pi) \\
&\ge U(f,\pi) - L(f,\pi) + \int_a^b s_1 - \int_a^b s_2 \\
&> U(f,\pi) - L(f,\pi) - \varepsilon,
\end{align*} and so $U(f,\pi) - L(f,\pi) < 2\varepsilon = \varepsilon'$, and we are done.